# Where can I see my log4j logs in a Servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, log4j

I have a Servlet and I wanted to log a message using log 4j, like this:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("DownloadServlet.class");
logger.info("Hello");
```

But I cannot find the log anywhere? Where is it saved? I am using a Tomcat server.

Comment: Check what [Appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) you have set. If you haven't set any, I do not believe there are any defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is logging in your console, while you running the project.
Your code is not saving logs to files.